# How tf.contrib.seq2seq.TrainingHelper can be replaced in TensorFlow 2.2

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I am trying to run the project from [GitHub](https://github.com/kunalBhashkar/tensorflow_spelling_correction) but I have a trouble with TrainingHelper. Now, I am stuck with it, I dont know how to convert it to tf2. The console always returns the error like this:

```
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow_addons.seq2seq' has no attribute 'TrainingHelper'
```

Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/seq2seq/TrainingSampler

The api is a bit different, though. Some parameters passed in the constructor in TrainingHelper, are passed in TrainingSampler.initialize() instead. Also there are minimal differences in some of the return values. So, you have to do some adaptation for code migration.